# Error with aictab(), replacement has 3 rows, data has 1

Tags: r, anova

I'm trying to use `aictab()` from the AICcmodavg to compare a set of ANOVA models. that code looks like this.

```
  block_b_1 <- aov(log(total + 1) ~ depth_strata + Year, data = zp_model_sheet_day)
  
  block_b_2 <- aov(log(total + 1) ~ depth_strata*Year, data = zp_model_sheet_day)
  
  block_b_3 <- aov(log(total + 1) ~ PAR, data = zp_model_sheet_day)
  
  blockB.set <- list(block_b_1, block_b_2, block_b_3)
  
  blockB.names <- list("Depth Layer + Year","Depth Layer*Year","PAR")
  
  aictab(blockB.set, modnames = blockB.names)
```

the `zp_model_sheet_day` data frame is a subset of `zp_model_sheet` via

```
zp_model_sheet_day <- zp_model_sheet %>%
  filter(day_night == "day")
```

When i run `aictab()` I get the following error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "K", value = c(9, 21, 18)) : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 1
```

I'm not really sure why this is happening, the error message in not particularly enlightening, so any assistance would be appreciate it.

For reference, I also have the following packages loaded:

```
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)
library(AICcmodavg)
library(car)
library(MASS)
library(rcompanion)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a silly mistake. The variable `blockB.names` should have been defined as a vector and not a list.